# embedding pre/post-compute operations in a dask.Array task graph

Tags: python, dask

I'm interested in creating a `dask.array.Array` that opens and closes a resource before/after `compute()`.  But, I'd like to make no assumptions about how the end-user is going to call `compute` *and* I'd like to avoid creating a custom dask `Array` subclass or proxy object, so I'm trying to embed the operations in the `__dask_graph__` underlying the array.

(aside: Please ignore for the moment caveats about using stateful objects in dask, I'm aware of the risks, this question is just about task graph manipulation).

Consider the following class, that simulates a file reader that must be in an *open* state in order to read a chunk, otherwise it segfaults.

```py
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np

class FileReader:
    _open = True

    def open(self):
        self._open = True

    def close(self):
        self._open = False

    def to_dask(self) -> da.Array:
        return da.map_blocks(
            self._dask_block,
            chunks=((1,) * 4, 4, 4),
            dtype=float,
        )

    def _dask_block(self):
        if not self._open:
            raise RuntimeError("Segfault!")
        return np.random.rand(1, 4, 4)
```

If file stays open, everything is fine, but if one closes the file, the dask array returned from `to_dask` will fail:

```py
>>> t = FileReader()
>>> darr = t.to_dask()
>>> t.close()
>>> darr.compute()  # RuntimeError: Segfault!
```

The current task graph looks like:

```py
>>> list(darr.dask)
[
    ('_dask_block-aa4daac0835bafe001693f9ac085683a', 0, 0, 0),
    ('_dask_block-aa4daac0835bafe001693f9ac085683a', 1, 0, 0),
    ('_dask_block-aa4daac0835bafe001693f9ac085683a', 2, 0, 0),
    ('_dask_block-aa4daac0835bafe001693f9ac085683a', 3, 0, 0)
]
```

essentially, I'd like to add new task to the beginning, that the `_dask_block` layer depends on, and a task to the end, that depends on `_dask_block`.

I tried directly manipulating the `HighLevelGraph` output of `da.map_blocks` to add these tasks manually, but found that they were getting pruned during compute optimizations, because `darr.__dask_keys__()` doesn't contain my keys (and, again, I'd like to avoid subclassing or requiring the end-user to call `compute` with special optimization flags).

One solution would be to make sure that the `_dask_block` function passed to map_blocks always opens and closes the underlying resource... but let's assume that the open/close process is relatively slow, effectively destroying performance for single-machine parallelism.  So we only want a single open at the beginning, and close at the end.

I can "cheat" a little to include a task that opens my file, by including a new key in my call to `map_blocks` as follows:

```py
    ...
    
    # new method that will run at beginning of compute()
    def _pre_compute(self):
        was_open = self._open
        if not was_open:
            self.open()
        return was_open

    def to_dask(self) -> da.Array:
        # new task key
        pre_task = 'pre_compute-' + tokenize(self._pre_compute)
        arr = da.map_blocks(
            self._dask_block,
            pre_task,  # add key here so all chunks depend on it
            chunks=((1,) * 4, 4, 4),
            dtype=float,
        )
        # add key to HighLevelGraph
        arr.dask.layers[pre_task] = {pre_task: (self._pre_compute,)}
        return da.Array(arr.dask, arr.name, arr.chunks, arr.dtype)

    # add "mock" argument to map_blocks function
    def _dask_block(self, _):
        if not self._open:
            raise RuntimeError("Segfault!")
        return np.random.rand(1, 4, 4)
```

so far so good, no more `RuntimeError`... but now I have leaked file handles, since nothing closes it at the end.

What I'd like then, is a task at the end of the graph that depends on both the output of `pre_task` (i.e. whether the file had to be opened for this compute), and closes the file if it had to be opened.

And here's where I'm stuck, since that `post-compute` key will get pruned by the optimizer...

is there any way to do this without creating a custom Array subclass that overrides methods like `__dask_postcompute__` or `__dask_keys__`, or requiring the end-user to call compute without optimization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a really interesting question. I think you are on the right track with editing the task graph to include tasks for opening and closing your shared resource. But manual graph manipulation is fiddly and difficult to get right.

I think the easiest way to accomplish what you want is to use some of the relatively-recently-added utilities for graph manipulation in [`dask.graph_manipulation`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/graph_manipulation.html). In particular, I think we want `bind`, which can be used to add implicit dependencies to a Dask collection, and `wait_for`, which can be used to ensure that *dependents* of a collection wait on another unrelated collection.

I took a pass at modifying your example to with these utilities to create a variety of `to_dask()` which is self-opening and closing:

```py
import dask
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np
from dask.graph_manipulation import bind, checkpoint, wait_on


class FileReader:
    _open = False

    def open(self):
        self._open = True

    def close(self):
        self._open = False

    def to_dask(self) -> da.Array:
        # Delayed version of self.open
        @dask.delayed
        def open_resource():
            self.open()
        # Delayed version of self.close
        @dask.delayed
        def close_resource():
            self.close()
            
        opener = open_resource()
        arr = da.map_blocks(
            self._dask_block,
            chunks=((1,) * 4, 4, 4),
            dtype=float,
        )
        # Make sure the array is dependent on `opener`
        arr = bind(arr, opener)

        closer = close_resource()
        # Make sure the closer is dependent on the array being done
        closer = bind(closer, arr)
        # Make sure dependents of arr happen after `closer` is done
        arr, closer = wait_on(arr, closer)
        return arr

    def _dask_block(self):
        if not self._open:
            raise RuntimeError("Segfault!")
        return np.random.rand(1, 4, 4)
```

I found it interesting to look at the task graph before and after the manipulations.

Before, it is a relatively straightforward chunked array:

[image: chunked-array-with-no-checkpoints-or-dependencies]

But after the manipulations, you can see that the array blocks depend on `open_resource`, and these then flow into `close_resource`, which then flows into letting the array chunks into the wider world:

[image: task-graph-visualization-self-opening-and-closing-array]

Comment: Thank you @IanRose!  bind and wait_on were exactly what I needed.  I really appreciate the time you took to answer so thoroughly :)